# How to set eth (not geth) data directory?

Tags: go-ethereum, cpp-ethereum

I could find solutions for geth to set the data directory

```
geth --datadir = ./chaindata
```

What is the eth alternative for the same?

Does it make a difference in using geth or eth client?

and how to initialize genesis.json

Answer (score 1):

if you use `eth --help` 
you will get

```
-d,--db-path,--datadir <path>  Load database from path (default: C:\Users\Tera_pc\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum).
```